# E: Unable to locate package snmp−mibs−downloader

Tags: ubuntu, mips, snmp

I'm  trying  to install a  smitools , so I start writing this command

```
  sudo apt install snmp−mibs−downloader
```

but when i run it this is result appear :

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package snmp−mibs−downloader
```

How can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

snmp-mibs-downloader available on ubuntu multiverse repository, be sure thats repository is active.

or you can download the package from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/snmp-mibs-downloader), adjust to the version you are using.